# R: finding indices of columns in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

```
m <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Width, data = iris)
beta = dfbetas(m)
> head(beta)
    (Intercept)   Sepal.Width   Petal.Width
1 -0.0018633253  0.0054762565 -0.0096031648
2  0.0094916858 -0.0062007468 -0.0137816086
3 -0.0221770886  0.0069280848  0.0540485812
4 -0.0408776612  0.0219247324  0.0731671391
5  0.0071436202 -0.0134636336  0.0150509697
6  0.0006264958 -0.0007979264  0.0001755277


apply(data.frame(beta), 2, function(x) which(abs(x) < 0.1632993))
```

I have a matrix named `beta` that contains 3 columns. After converting it to type `data.frame`, I wanted to find the indices using the `which` function of observations whose absolute values are < 0.1632993. Essentially I want a list of indices for each column. But my apply function doesn't seem to do what I wanted it to do.

Comment: It could be in any format as long as it tells me which observation (s) meet my criterion of `abs(value) < 0.1632993` for EACH column of my data.frame.

Comment: The `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE` gives the row/column index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE` on the entire dataset to get the `row/column` indexes

```
which(abs(beta) < 0.1632993, arr.ind=TRUE)
```